# Make a two option field read-only if it is true on load

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

I am wondering if there is any OOB way to make a two-option field read-only if a form loaded the two-option field as "true".

I know I can use Javascript and the OnLoad event on the form to accomplish this, but I want to try and use as many OOB features as possible.

Comment: you will need a Business Rule or a JavaScript for this

Comment: @JSantosh I don't have any code at the moment.  It is just a question if I can make this happen in CRM without using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct scenarios:

1. The field should be read-only *only* if the field is *Yes* on form load.
2. The field should be read-only as soon as the value of the field is changed to Yes.

In case 1 you will have to use custom javascript.

In case 2 you can use [Business Rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531086.aspx) as Guido also mentions in the comments. In this case you would create a business rule with a condition checking whether the value of your field equals Yes. If so, you would lock the field (resulting in it being read-only).

Comment: Yes, case 1 is what I want.  I knew I could use javascript.  I was just wondering if there was another way to get the same functionality for scenario 1 without using javascript.

Comment: OK. In that case you do not have any out-of-the-box solutions, so javascript would be the way forward.

Comment: You can use business rules for onload too.

Comment: Yes, but business rules cannot be set to run only onload (it will also run onchange)